# Add to cart button is redirecting to check out page

Tags: addtocart, product-view

If we click on "add to cart" button , it's redirecting to "checkout page", but it should stay on same page.

This is our addtocart.phtml   http://pastebin.com/37P4wUdb

Please help me to find solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set that in admin panel itself.

Goto

> Admin > System > Configuration > Checkout > Shopping Cart > After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart > No.

[image: Admin Config]

Comment: but its refreshing the page.

is there any option to add the cart to item without refreshing?

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2

> Stores > Configuration > Configuration > Sales > Checkout > After
>   Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart > Yes